# Local versus global packages for Angular development

Tags: npm, package, versioning

When developing with Angular, one can

```
npm install
```

to install packages locally, or

```
npm install -g
```

to install them globally. I am wondering what are the implications of each practice. And what happens if a particular package is installed both ways, perhaps with different versions? Which one will my Angular app use?

Comment: Depends which packages you're talking about. Basically the only things you should be installing globally are command line tools (and usually you should install them locally *as well* - most of them delegate to the local install if it exists).

Comment: Ugh, ok, typically there are hundreds of them. I need to define a practice for myself that makes sense, and then to follow it.

Comment: In an Angular project, I would install `@angular/cli` globally, and then use it to scaffold the project (which will automatically install local versions of the rest of the tools).

Answer (score 1):

From there https://www.quora.com/When-do-I-install-a-package-locally-or-globally-in-NPM

In general, the rule of thumb is:
1. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your program, using
import { 'whatever'}, then install it locally, at the root of your project.
2. If you’re installing something that you want to use in your shell, on the command line or something, install it globally, so that its binaries end up in your PATH environment variable.